# Redirect to Client Based On user login access in identity server 4?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

i have centralized login application which is developed by using identity server 4.now i want to redirect user based on login access for example user A is only access employee.ab.com module .

how can i redirect user based on module access>

Comment: I can imagine that a user can access more than one module. So what should happen if user A can access two or more modules?

Comment: one user only access one default module

Answer (score 0):

Better to redirect back to a common starting page, and then in the client application redirect the user to the module the user have access too. Not everything should be handled inside IdentityServer.